# TypeScript does not see that undefined\null value checking has been executed in variable

Tags: typescript

In below example, TypeScript does not see that `parameters.a` and `parameters.b` has been checked for undefined value and in `transformValue(parameters.a)` line **could not** be undefined:

```js
type Example = {
    a?: string,
    b?: string
}

function example(parameters: {
    a?: string,
    b?: string,
    skipA?: boolean,
    skipB?: boolean
}): Example {

    const shouldReturnA = typeof parameters.a !== "undefined" && parameters.skipA !== false;
    const shouldReturnB = typeof parameters.b !== "undefined" && parameters.skipB !== false;

    return {
        ...shouldReturnA ? { a: transformValue(parameters.a) } : {},
        ...shouldReturnB ? { b: transformValue(parameters.b) } : {}
    }
}

function transformValue(targetValue: string): string {
    return targetValue + "~~~";
}
```

```
Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2345)

Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2345)
```

[Fiddle](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Well, I can rewrite this synthetic example like this:

```js
function example(parameters: {
    a?: string,
    b?: string,
    skipA?: boolean,
    skipB?: boolean
}): Example {
  return {
      ...typeof parameters.a !== "undefined" && parameters.skipA !== false ? { 
        a: transformValue(parameters.a) 
      } : {},
      ...shouldReturnB = typeof parameters.b !== "undefined" && parameters.skipB !== false ? { 
        b: transformValue(parameters.b) 
      } : {}
  }
}
```

But how about below live example?

```
public static normalizeRawConfig(
  {
    pickedFromConsoleInputConfig,
    rawValidConfigFromFile
  }: {
    pickedFromConsoleInputConfig: ProjectBuilderRawConfigNormalizer.PickedFromConsoleInputConfig;
    rawValidConfigFromFile: ProjectBuilderRawValidConfigFromFile;
  }
): ProjectBuilderNormalizedConfig {

  const markupPreprocessingConfigNormalizingIsRequired: boolean =
      !isUndefined(rawValidConfigFromFile[ProjectBuilderTasksIDsForConfigFile.markupPreprocessing]) &&
      (
          isUndefined(pickedFromConsoleInputConfig.tasksAndSourceFilesSelection) ||
          Object.keys(pickedFromConsoleInputConfig.tasksAndSourceFilesSelection)
              .includes(ProjectBuilderTasksIDsForConfigFile.markupPreprocessing)
      );

  const stylesPreprocessingConfigNormalizingIsRequired: boolean =
      !isUndefined(rawValidConfigFromFile[ProjectBuilderTasksIDsForConfigFile.stylesPreprocessing]) &&
      (
          isUndefined(pickedFromConsoleInputConfig.tasksAndSourceFilesSelection) ||
          Object.keys(pickedFromConsoleInputConfig.tasksAndSourceFilesSelection)
              .includes(ProjectBuilderTasksIDsForConfigFile.stylesPreprocessing)
      );

  return {
    ...markupPreprocessingConfigNormalizingIsRequired ? {
      markupPreprocessing: MarkupPreprocessingRawSettingsNormalizer.getNormalizedSettings(
          rawValidConfigFromFile.markupPreprocessing, commonSettings__normalized
      )
    } : {},
    ...stylesPreprocessingConfigNormalizingIsRequired ? {} : {
      stylesPreprocessing: StylesPreprocessingRawSettingsNormalizer.getNormalizedSettings(
          rawValidConfigFromFile.stylesPreprocessing, commonSettings__normalized
      )
    }
  };
}
```

If rewrite it without `markupPreprocessingConfigNormalizingIsRequired` and `stylesPreprocessingConfigNormalizingIsRequired`, it will become to:

```js
return {
  ...!isUndefined(rawValidConfigFromFile[ProjectBuilderTasksIDsForConfigFile.markupPreprocessing]) &&
    (
        isUndefined(pickedFromConsoleInputConfig.tasksAndSourceFilesSelection) ||
        Object.keys(pickedFromConsoleInputConfig.tasksAndSourceFilesSelection)
            .includes(ProjectBuilderTasksIDsForConfigFile.markupPreprocessing)
    ) ? {
    markupPreprocessing: MarkupPreprocessingRawSettingsNormalizer.getNormalizedSettings(
        rawValidConfigFromFile.markupPreprocessing, commonSettings__normalized
    )
  } : {},
  ...!isUndefined(rawValidConfigFromFile[ProjectBuilderTasksIDsForConfigFile.stylesPreprocessing]) &&
    (
        isUndefined(pickedFromConsoleInputConfig.tasksAndSourceFilesSelection) ||
        Object.keys(pickedFromConsoleInputConfig.tasksAndSourceFilesSelection)
            .includes(ProjectBuilderTasksIDsForConfigFile.stylesPreprocessing)
    ) ? {
    stylesPreprocessing: StylesPreprocessingRawSettingsNormalizer.getNormalizedSettings(
        rawValidConfigFromFile.stylesPreprocessing, commonSettings__normalized
    )
  } : {}
};
```

And also, the conditions will become complicated in the future.

Some best practices to dealing with it in TypeScirpt?

### Update

Tried to comparing `XXX !== undefined` instead of `typeof XXX !== "undefined`. Same effect.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Why doesn't it recognize undefined checking was done?

The underlying issue that causes the TS compiler to not realize `a` or `b` have been checked has to do with how "type guards" work.  You have a type guard in your code `parameters.a !== undefined` (the check on `skipX` has nothing to do with type checking, so leaving that out of example).  If you were to use that like this:

```
if (parameters.a !== undefined) {
  transformValue(parameters.a)
}
```

TS would be perfectly happy with that, *because the `transformValue` call is inside the if statement*.  That is how type guards work, TS uses them to "narrow" the type of the variable with in the if block.  In your case, TS is not setup to understand that you previously narrowed the type when you set the value for `shouldReturnA`--humans can see the logic of it, but to TS that is ancient history which it has forgotten about by the time it gets to your `...shouldReturnA ?`  code.

#### Alternate approach

This is not as quick a fix as @dongnhan's suggestion to use `!` after the variable, but maybe you will like it.  I think it organizes the logic a bit better and makes it a bit more DRY, but that is my opinion.

```
type Example = {
    a?: string,
    b?: string
}

function example(parameters: {
    a?: string,
    b?: string,
    skipA?: boolean,
    skipB?: boolean
}): Example {

    const validatedProp = (prop: string | undefined, shouldSkip: boolean | undefined) => 
      !shouldSkip && typeof prop === "string" ? { a: transformValue(prop) } : {}

    return {
        ...validatedProp(parameters.a, parameters.skipA),
        ...validatedProp(parameters.b, parameters.skipB),
    }
}

function transformValue(targetValue: string): string {
    return targetValue + "~~~";
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHgQwLZgDbQLxQN4CgoFQID8AXFAM7ABOAlgHYDmANPoQEZmU0OO4C%20uXADMArvQDGwWgHt6UCIhToAFGATVkEYBGoVyeQkS5U6TVkc7lTvC4QoBrWmACCXdjJnoE9OwUfOAELunt70AgCU5PDIaNB4bAQSclRQAG4IqLQAJgg62QAK1DJgUFhqxWDWPExQAD5Q4tkQwgwQ2cyUABYyoqjZAMpOVVAeXhA%209Y30za307RFlAHxQiYQAhBQ9fYPDUABk%201CgkDLCUGCVZRhYAEQ2TLdQxDhE5DQ%20FMIy1EgAaplRBAKiVFvwoAZBGtqNpRNR5IYjIQAHSojJZXL5IolNQaLQ6PTIhCddSaJDaXQUZEBVwRPxI1HI9E5PLtbFgXFkimE9gkvHkglUmmBOlrQRQsSSaRyY6aehfH7-QHA4AaRjaAGoIHVMyMKLcXU4aGw%20HHNUa5VQADUUFuAD8HbcANwCIA)
Still room for much more improvement with further refactoring.

#### My Opinion About `typeof` `undefined` vs `'undefined'`

Please listen to ESLint on this one.  The `typeof` keyword will return a string "undefined", not the value `undefined`.  Your type guard will not work unless you use the string (although note I compare for the positive match to "string")

Answer (score 3):

Based on the [Typescript handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator), there is something called **non-null assertion operator**:

> A new `!` post-fix expression operator may be used to assert that its operand is non-null and non-undefined in contexts where the type checker is unable to conclude that fact. Specifically, the operation x! produces a value of the type of x with null and undefined excluded. Similar to type assertions of the forms `<T>x` and `x as T`, the `!` non-null assertion operator is simply removed in the emitted JavaScript code.

```
type Example = {
    a?: string,
    b?: string
}

function example(parameters: {
    a?: string,
    b?: string,
    skipA?: boolean,
    skipB?: boolean
}): Example {

    const shouldReturnA = parameters.a !== undefined && parameters.skipA !== false;
    const shouldReturnB = parameters.b !== undefined && parameters.skipB !== false;

    return {
        ...shouldReturnA ? { a: transformValue(parameters.a!) } : {},
        ...shouldReturnB ? { b: transformValue(parameters.b as string) } : {} // another way
    }
}

function transformValue(targetValue: string): string {
    return targetValue + "~~~";
}
```

Here's one helpful article about non-null assertion operator: https://medium.com/better-programming/cleaner-typescript-with-the-non-null-assertion-operator-300789388376

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I don't consider the ESLint as single source of truth, but the rule ESLint [no-undefined](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undefined) tells that "parameters.a !== undefined" is not good...

Comment: Why is it not good then? `Because undefined can be overwritten or shadowed`. To be honest, you would never want to do that in your code (it's obviously a bad practice to reassign or to shadow the `undefined` variable). So you could safely turn off or ignore this rule (ignore on single line or on the whole file, eslint supports this ignoring syntax)

Comment: Thank you for critical thinking. I'll consider the issue to ESLint.

Comment: Please allow me one more question. What ESLint documentation means when told "doesn't do what you think it does" about `data === undefined`?

Comment: On the upper line, the `undefined` is being shadowed: `var undefined = "hi"`. That leads to `data === undefined` to be interpreted as `data === "hi"` (which is not to be expected).

Comment: Got it! Thank you again for the explanations.

Comment: I am sorry, I checked your solution and it does not work. If you'd just be kind to continue this conversation, please check my updated question.

Comment: typescript is not perfect and it seems it cannot resolve such situation itself. you can use bang operator to say "hey ts, on this line it is surely not null". `transformValue(parameters!.a)`

Comment: Thanks @Andrei for pointing that out, the operator is called non-null assertion operator. Actually in this case, you would place the `!` at the end like this: `transformValue(parameters.a!)`. With some research, I've updated the answer and includes a helpful article.